# Shell script get real time from 'time' and save to variable

Tags: shell

I'm trying to make a shell script for my program to take time multiple times and then divide to get an average time for it to execute.

What I've tried is following:

```
time [./finder -p ARG1 ARG2 ARG3] > /dev/null 2>&1 | grep real | awk '{print $2}'
```

Basically I want to remove the output of my program, so I'm trying to redirect the output to null. I also want to remove the output of time. It's barely working and I also need to save the result in a variable so I can run it in a loop. Any ideas how that can be done?

Comment: `[./finder -p ARG1 ARG2 ARG3]` looks like Tcl; the rest looks like standard POSIX shell.

Comment: [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032): *How can I redirect the output of 'time' to a variable or file?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beware: "time" can be a shell builtin. Invoke as /usr/bin/time or with env to avoid the builtin and get proper pipeline and output behavior:

```
env time bash -c './finder >/dev/null' 2>&1 | awk '$2 == "real" {print $1}'
```

Also, it Would Be Bad to direct 1 to null, and then immediately direct 2 to the same place.

You can surround with backticks and assign to variable, or for simpler punctuation redirect to a temp file and then use:

```
ELAPSED=`cat time.txt`
```

Here is some example output that awk is parsing:

```
$ env time pwd
/tmp
        0.01 real         0.00 user         0.00 sys
```

The `-p` switch can be passed if you prefer POSIX output:

```
$ env time -p pwd
/tmp
real         0.01
user         0.00
sys          0.00
```

Here is one way to grab raw time stderr output in a variable:

```
$ TIME=`env time pwd 2>&1 | tail -1`
$ echo $TIME
0.00 real 0.00 user 0.00 sys
```

Comment: This is not printing out anything for me. How do I save the result 0.000 time in a variable?

Comment: You can use the builtin `command`; `env` isn't necessary. `command time bash -c '...'`.

Answer (score 0):

Via "*intermediate*" temporary file and *format* `-f` option:

```
real_time_val=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%e" -o tmpfile [./finder -p ARG1 ARG2 ARG3] > /dev/null 2>&1 && cat tmpfile)
```

---

- `%e` - Elapsed real (wall clock) time used by the process, in seconds.
- `-o FILE` - Write the resource use statistics to `FILE` instead of to the standard error stream

Exemplary result:

```
$ echo "$real_time_val" 
0.02
```